# Pass array data through AJAX and get in python file(views.py)

Tags: python, arrays, django, ajax, django-templates

I want to pass array data in views.py file for that I use AJAX and passing data through AJAX. But there I am not able to get all data in views.py file, some of the data are missing.

display.html

```
      var SelectedID = [];
      function getvalues() {
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
          SelectedID[i] = $(this).val();
          console.log("Selected Data", SelectedID[i])
                 
          $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'addtoexisting' bid=adduser.id %}",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data:{
              SelectedID : SelectedID[i],
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
             },
             success: function (data) {
               console.log("Selected Data AJAX", SelectedID)
               alert("Successfully sent the Data to Django");
              },
              error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                // alert("Could not send URL to Django. Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
              }
            });
          });
       }
```

views.py

```
def display(request):
     is_ajax = request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
     if is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
          SelectedID = request.POST.get('SelectedID')
          print(SelectedID)
return render(request, 'display.html',{})
```

SelectedID[i] = $(this).val(); in this selectedID There are 10 records but in print of views.py there is only 6 records, other data are missing.

Comment: did you try to `console.log( SelectedID[i])`? How much records did you receive on console?

Comment: Yes, I tried it already. It gives all 10 records.

Comment: I have no idea try to give setTimeout to see the process

Comment: Maybe it will help: `request.POST.getlist('SelectedID')`

Comment: With getlist() I get list But I want to pass SelectedID in Queryset like this, AddContact.objects.filter(id=SelectedID).  Using getlist, it gives error on that part.

Comment: I think there might be a formatting issue at the bottom of the first code snippet (brace is outside of the code block) -- can you double-check?